# Get all of the starting and endpoints of a loop out of prompt

Tags: javascript, for-loop, double, var, prompt

Why is this working:

```
<html>
<title> JavaScript Tutorial 1
</title>
<body>
<script language = "javascript">

var a, b, c, d, j, k, sum;
// a = window.prompt("Enter a Number");
 b = window.prompt("Enter a Number");
 c = window.prompt("Enter a Number");
 d = window.prompt("Enter a Number");

a = 5;
//b = 15;
//c = 1;
//d = 8;

sum = 0;
for (j = a; j <= b; j++) {

    for (k = c ; k <= d ; k++) {
        sum += j * j * k;
    }
}

// document.write("<br>")
document.write(sum);

</script>
<noscript>
<p> You have JavaScript Turned Off <p>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

While this isn't:

```
<html>
<title> JavaScript Tutorial 1
</title>
<body>
<script language = "javascript">

var a, b, c, d, j, k, sum;
 a = window.prompt("Enter a Number");
 b = window.prompt("Enter a Number");
 c = window.prompt("Enter a Number");
 d = window.prompt("Enter a Number");

//a = 5;
//b = 15;
//c = 1;
//d = 8;

sum = 0;
for (j = a; j <= b; j++) {

    for (k = c ; k <= d ; k++) {
        sum += j * j * k;
    }
}

// document.write("<br>")
document.write(sum);

</script>
<noscript>
<p> You have JavaScript Turned Off <p>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm curious about this one, if i would change and set b as 15 but take a as variable it would work as well. i don't get it.

By the way the rules that are given on this side to post a question are just stupid ass... why should i write mor about the issue if the code it self represents it best? so better think about your posting rules!

i have a simple question and with the 2 code brackets i think i pointed out well what i'm going to try to do.

hopefully this was now enough to actually post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the `window.prompt` returns a `String`.

When you declare the `a` variable as `a = 5;`, you're ensuring it is a `Number`, and then, all the other calculations are automatically converted to `Number` by the browser engines.

But if you don't do that, then, it tries to concatenate the strings, and it doesn't work as expected.

---

You can see what I'm talking about, if you declare `a = '5';` and you will see that it will work exactly as it works when you use all the variables through the `window.prompt`.

And you can parse the `window.prompt` return as a `Number`, if you want to make it works:

```
a = Number(window.prompt("Enter a Number"));
```

Look at [this fiddle I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/z6yjj53g/) with the code above.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanaion, this works just as a charme ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you do a, `a = window.prompt("Enter a Number");` the result is a string type and not a number. Naturally the problem would arise here, `for (j = a; j <= b; j++)`

You got to parse it with [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)  and ensure that `a` is of **number** type before the for loop in your program.